# How to get GPS coordinates for markers placed on google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created a layer in Google Maps and have marked some places of my interest and have thus created a database of around 30 places. Is it possible to retrieve GPS coordinates for each of these locations programmatically and store them on local computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export them as KML file. There you will have your points.

Export link is in the left part of window, below the name of the map:

```
Rate this map · Write a comment · KML ·
```